# How to bulk download and install the latest version of a set of free apps?

Tags: download, package-management

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [One-stop-shop installer for free Windows software?](https://superuser.com/questions/69751/one-stop-shop-installer-for-free-windows-software)

Once I saw an app that could download and install the newest version of a set of freeware defined by the user. I can't recall the name of these programs. I could use it to install, let's say:

- 7-zip
- Google Chrome
- Foobar2000

Across many computers without having to enter each of those sites manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [Ninite](http://ninite.com/). It builds a custom installer that installs all the free apps you choose from their web page.

Comment: I'm certain that's not the only option, but surely is what I was looking for.

Comment: Some other options: http://alternativeto.net/software/ninite/